# Different emails for different firebase users Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have 2 kinds of users.

- Admin.
- User.

And there are 2 registrations.

After registration, you will receive a confirmation email. How to make a different email structure for different users?

For example:

Hello Admin, please confirm your email.

and for the user:

Hi User, please verify your email.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in email verification feature if Firebase Authentication uses a single email template for all users and doesn't allow customization of the content of the email.

If you want to send different emails to different types of users, you'll have to take control of the entire verification process. Once you've verified the email address, you can [use the Admin SDK to set the `emailVerified` flag of the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).